# Zend framework 2: catch exception in layout

Tags: zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2 (ZF2), I can throw exception in the controller, and catching by attaching a `dispatch.error` listener to the event manager from the Module class.

Is there a way to  **catch an exception thrownfrom the layout** (phtml) from a view helper ?

Comment: Which version of ZF2 are you using?

Comment: Actually phtml files (view layer) shouldn't thrown an exception.

Comment: @foozy sometimes, you can't do anything against it. Think about view helpers you include.

Comment: @JurianSluiman I'm using zf2 2.2.1